# Flicker image when bind image in RecyclerView item using DataBinding

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, android-databinding

I use `DataBinding` for bind image in RecyclerView item like the code below then it make image flicker when I reload all RecyclerView (by notifyDataSetChange)
If I don't use `DataBinding` and just set image normally, the image don't flicker
What did I do wrong with `DataBinding` ? Any help or suggestion would be great appreciated

My RecyclerView adapter code

```
public class RecyclerViewAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<RecyclerViewAdapter.MyViewHolder> {
    private Context mContext;
    private List<String> list;
    public static class MyViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
        ItemBinding mBinding;
        public MyViewHolder(ItemBinding mBinding) {
            super(mBinding.getRoot());
            this.mBinding = mBinding;
            mBinding.setViewHolder(this);
        }

        public int getSrc(){
            return R.drawable.ic_launcher;
        }
    }
    public RecyclerViewAdapter(Context context, List<String> moviesList) {
        this.mContext = context;
        this.list = moviesList;
    }
    @Override
    public MyViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        ItemBinding binding =
                DataBindingUtil.inflate(LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()), R.layout.item,
                        parent, false);
        return new MyViewHolder(binding);
    }
    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(MyViewHolder holder, int position) {
    }
    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return list.size();
    }
    @BindingAdapter({ "src" })
    public static void setImageSrc(ImageView view, int src) {
        if (src != -1) view.setImageResource(src);
    }
}
```

My item xml

```
<layout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
>
    <data>
        <variable
            name="viewHolder"
            type="example.toong.testreloadimageusingglidebynotifydatasetchangewithdatabinding.RecyclerViewAdapter.MyViewHolder"
        />
    </data>
    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@drawable/bg_holding_three_gradient_layer"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/imageView"
            android:layout_width="100dp"
            android:layout_height="100dp"
            app:src="@{viewHolder.src}"
        />

    </LinearLayout>
</layout>
```

[image]

Demo Project: https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B_poNaia6t8kVlBfSGJ4QU9uZHc/view

Comment: Are the images network images? caching and loading?

Comment: @OBX it just the image in drawable file (ic_launcher), you can see in my code. `app:src="@{viewHolder.src}"` and  `public int getSrc(){
            return R.drawable.ic_launcher;
        }`

Comment: Did you try with some image loading library? Like picasso ? May be it should help

Comment: @OBX I test it with Glide and still don't work. but I have mention in my question (if I don't use DataBinding the problem don't happend) so I do think that image loading library is not the problem

Comment: Can you give it a try with `binding.executePendingBindings()` instead of `notifyDataSetChange()` ?

Comment: @RaviRupareliya how do I use `binding.executePendingBindings()`? I don't know where to put this code

Comment: Where are you using `notifyDataSetChange()`?

Comment: I have a MainActivity, that contain a Tab, Tab contain 2 Fragment, I call adapter.notifyDataSetChange() inside `setUserVisibleHint` of each Fragment

Comment: If you have implemented `DataBinding` in `Fragment` you can use `fragmentBinding.executePendingBindings();` there

Comment: @RaviRupareliya RecyclerView don't reload after I call `fragmentBinding.executePendingBindings();`

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I think the step you're missing is that you must use `executePendingBindings()`:

```
@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(MyViewHolder holder, int position) {
    // Normally, you'd do the binding here, but yours is static.
    holder.mBinding.executePendingBindings();
}
```

For an article on this topic:
https://medium.com/google-developers/android-data-binding-recyclerview-db7c40d9f0e4#.24tuxwvsh

Answer (score 1):

There are two ways perhaps could help you

1.Write your own Adapter

.notifyDataSetChange() .Couldn't workwell in Databinding

```
public class BindingRecyclerView {

public static abstract class ListAdapter<T, VH extends ViewHolder> extends RecyclerView.Adapter<VH> {

    protected final LayoutInflater inflater;
    protected final ObservableList<T> data;

    private final AtomicInteger refs = new AtomicInteger();

    private final ObservableList.OnListChangedCallback<ObservableList<T>> callback =
            new ObservableList.OnListChangedCallback<ObservableList<T>>() {
                @Override
                public void onChanged(ObservableList<T> sender) {
                    notifyDataSetChanged();
                }

                @Override
                public void onItemRangeChanged(ObservableList<T> sender,
                                               int positionStart, int itemCount) {
                    notifyItemRangeChanged(positionStart, itemCount);
                }

                @Override
                public void onItemRangeInserted(ObservableList<T> sender,
                                                int positionStart, int itemCount) {
                    notifyItemRangeInserted(positionStart, itemCount);
                }

                @Override
                public void onItemRangeMoved(ObservableList<T> sender,
                                             int fromPosition, int toPosition, int itemCount) {
                    for (int i = 0; i < itemCount; i++) {
                        notifyItemMoved(fromPosition + i, toPosition + i);
                    }
                }

                @Override
                public void onItemRangeRemoved(ObservableList<T> sender,
                                               int positionStart, int itemCount) {
                    notifyItemRangeRemoved(positionStart, itemCount);
                }
            };

    public ListAdapter(Context context, ObservableList<T> data) {
        this.inflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);
        this.data = data;
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return data.size();
    }

    @Override
    public void onAttachedToRecyclerView(RecyclerView recyclerView) {
        if (refs.getAndIncrement() == 0) {
            data.addOnListChangedCallback(callback);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onDetachedFromRecyclerView(RecyclerView recyclerView) {
        if (refs.decrementAndGet() == 0) {
            data.removeOnListChangedCallback(callback);
        }
    }

}

public static class ViewHolder<V extends ViewDataBinding> extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {

    public final V binding;

    public ViewHolder(LayoutInflater inflater, @LayoutRes int layoutId, ViewGroup parent) {
        this(DataBindingUtil.<V>inflate(inflater, layoutId, parent, false));
    }

    public ViewHolder(V binding) {
        super(binding.getRoot());
        this.binding = binding;
    }
}}
```

2.When you have refresh your data make new Adapter don't use the old one.
It might also help

The first class didn't wrote by me.But it did worked out in our project.
When I use PageAdapter It also won't REfresh by  .notifyDataSetChange()
But in that adapter I can use another way to force refresh.So I know a little about this.Hope this would be helpful.....

Comment: thank you for you answer
1. I have wrote my RecyclerView adapter (that is in my question), I see your adapter but I can not see the different thing that can help me solve my problem. Please help me explain more
2. I need refesh all RecyclerView so I must use notifyDataSetChange

Comment: notifyDataSetChange will  not effect when you using Databinding .so 2 means after you change your data make a new adapter instead of use notifyDataSetChange to refresh it

Comment: I don't think so, when I use notifyDataSetChange, the RecryclerView refresh.